# Powershell Unserialize Function?

Tags: powershell

First time poster.

I have a project that requires querying data from a MySQL Wordpress site database. Some of this data is serialized so my question is there an option available with powershell that is equivalent to the PHP unserialize() method?

Thank you.

Comment: Serialized how? Note that "serialization" is just the general name for turning an object into a string or binary format; there is no one canonical way to do serialization. If it's serialized the way PHP deserializes, then no, there is no native cmdlet in PowerShell to deserialize PHP-serialized data. It would certainly be possible to write one, and perhaps there are already libraries out there that do so, though recommending any of those would be off-topic for SO.

Comment: `unserialize()` turns a string into a PHP runtime object - PowerShell is not PHP :-)

Comment: I’m presuming the OP has stored some data in a database using the PHP serialise() function and now wants to derserialize it in Powershell to do some processing. Here’s the PHP serialisation format for anyone interested... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP_serialization_format

Comment: Thanks for the comments and explanation. My technical contact only mentioned the fields were serialized with WordPress PHP. Here's example data if this helps:

Original:
a:2:{i:0;s:2:"28";i:1;s:2:"24";}

Ran through PHP unserialize method:
Array
(
    [0] => 28
    [1] => 24
)

As a workaround, I am running the data through PHP and scrapping it through Powershell. It works however it is slow. I was just wondering if a function or community library existed that would be more efficient. From the sounds of it, it does not based off my on my searching. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how your data got serialized.

If you are going to serialize with Powershell, store it in a DB, and then deserialize you can do this:

```
$serialized = [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize($myObject)
[System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Deserialize($serialized)
```

if you have serialized base64 to UTF8, you can do this:

```
[Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Deserialize([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String($YourData)))
```

You can also store the data (serialized or not) as JSon, and then to get an object back you can do `ConvertFrom-Json`. I prepared this example: https://code.labstack.com/-fHqQaRl

```
$myObject = @{a=1; b=2}
$myJsonObject = ConvertTo-Json $myObject
$mySerializedJsonObject = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($myJsonObject))

# Deserializing:
$myDeserializedJsonObject = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([System.Convert]::FromBase64String($mySerializedJsonObject))
$myDeserializedObject = ConvertFrom-Json $myDeserializedJsonObject

Write-Verbose "My initial object: $($myObject.a)" -Verbose
Write-Verbose "My Json object: $myJsonObject" -Verbose
Write-Verbose "My Serialized object: $mySerializedJsonObject" -Verbose

Write-Verbose "My Deserialized Json: $myDeserializedJsonObject" -Verbose
Write-Verbose "My deserialized object: $($myDeserializedObject.a)" -Verbose
```

The output:

```
VERBOSE: My initial object: 1
VERBOSE: My Json object: {
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2
}
VERBOSE: My Serialized object: ewAKACAAIAAiAGEAIgA6ACAAMQAsAAoAIAAgACIAYgAiADoAIAAyAAoAfQA=
VERBOSE: My Deserialized Json: {
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2
}
VERBOSE: My deserialized object: 1
```